# Getting Matlab plot to scroll

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am trying to plot data from the serial port which is being sent from a micro controller, interpret this data and graph it. The data will be coming in very fast (every 50 of so micro seconds) so once I get to a certain number of data points read I would like to scroll the graph along. I have been able to successfully graph a single data value and multiple data values without scrolling however when I try to implement a scroll the values are distorted and my code usually breaks when I reach the value to begin scrolling at.

```
delete(instrfind);
clear;
close all;

s = serial('COM3'); %assigns the object s to serial port

set(s, 'InputBufferSize', 1); %number of bytes in inout buffer
set(s, 'FlowControl', 'hardware');
set(s, 'BaudRate', 9600);
set(s, 'Parity', 'none');
set(s, 'DataBits', 8);
set(s, 'StopBit', 1);
set(s, 'Timeout',10);
%s.Terminator = '"';
clc;

disp(get(s,'Name'));
prop(1)=(get(s,'BaudRate'));
prop(2)=(get(s,'DataBits'));
prop(3)=(get(s, 'StopBit'));
prop(4)=(get(s, 'InputBufferSize'));

disp(['Port Setup Done!!',num2str(prop)]);

fopen(s);           %opens the serial port
t=1;
a = zeros(100,'int8');
dataToDisplay = zeros(100,'int8');
disp('Running');


dataToDisplay = [];
while(t < 501)  %Runs for 500 cycles

       for x = 1:4
       a(x) = fread(s); %reads 3 values of the data from the serial port and stores it to the matrix a
       end

       if (t>101)
           for i = 1:98
           dataToDisplay(100) = ((a(1)-96)*10)+(a(2)-80)+((a(3)-32)/10); % combines the values in a and changes them into the value to display
           dataToDisplay(i) = dataToDisplay(i+1);
           end
       else
           dataToDisplay(t) = ((a(1)-96)*10)+(a(2)-80)+((a(3)-32)/10);
   end




   %if(data(t) == 10)
   %dataToDisplay(t) = a;   

   plot(dataToDisplay,'-*r');
   axis auto;
   grid on;
   hold on;

   t=t+1;
   x = 0;
   a=0;  %Clear the buffer
   drawnow;
end

fclose(s); %close the serial port
```

I should also add that the values I am reading are to be display simultaneously on 4 seven segment displays thus the decoding required to get the number to the form I wish to display. The first 3 displays hold the number while the fourth holds the unit which is not required in the matlab code at the moment.

Comment: Are you sure you need this `hold on`? Moreover, I would probably define the axis manually, as it would probably be much easier to read.

Comment: Right now I am just trying to get the scrolling to work cause ideally eventually I will have different subplots with different axis set manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code breaks because of what is assumedly a typo:

```
       dataToDisplay(i) = dataToDisplay(i+1);
```

Once t = 102, it requests the value of dataToDisplay(103), which doesn't exist yet.

What are you trying to accomplish with the following lines? I think there's a disparity between your logic and your implementation

```
if (t>101)
       for i = 1:98
       dataToDisplay(100) = ((a(1)-96)*10)+(a(2)-80)+((a(3)-32)/10); % combines the values in a and changes them into the value to display
       dataToDisplay(i) = dataToDisplay(i+1);
       end
   else
       dataToDisplay(t) = ((a(1)-96)*10)+(a(2)-80)+((a(3)-32)/10);
end
```

EDIT: Assuming that the comment below is the correct guess at what you're trying to do, I would change your code to the following (See my notes with %%%):

```
data = []; %%%Renamed variable
numSamples = 500; %%%Set numSamples as a variable, so that if you need this number later you can just change it once
figure; %%%Start figure before loop
axis auto;
grid on;

for t=1:numSamples %Runs for 500 cycles %%% More standard to use for loops than rolling your own with while and incrementing

     for x = 1:3 %%% Unsure why you had this set as 1:4, since you didn't read the fourth value
        a(x) = fread(s); %reads 3 values of the data from the serial port and stores it to the matrix a
    end

    data(t) = ((a(1)-96)*10)+(a(2)-80)+((a(3)-32)/10); %Update current value of data

    plot(data(max(1,t-100):t),'-*r'); %%%Plot the most recent 100 values

    %%% Unnecessary, variable clears when for x=1:3 loop ends   x = 0;
    %%% Unnecessary, a is reassigned when assigned to fre   a=0;  %Clear the buffer
    drawnow;
end
```

This way, you utilize normal for loops rather than making your own, cut down on unnecessary commands which makes your code less legible and worse-performing, and retain the entirety of "data" at the end in case you need to re-reference it.

Comment: I think he is trying to do the following: "append the first 100 values into `dataToDisplay`, then append the new ones at the end and shift the whole by one (fifo). You might be right, I didn't check the implementation, and there are definitely easier ways to achieve this, such as dataToDisplay(:) = [dataToDisplay(2:end),newdata]

Comment: Assuming that is correct, I have updated with EDIT1 above, to suggest ways to clean up this code and actually accomplish the goal

Comment: sorry I think I included a bit too much code but your answer is exactly what I was looking for 
        especially plot(data(max(1,t-100):t),'-*r'); %%%Plot the most recent      100 values

Comment: Ok so after some more testing im finding that the max function returns the max value? as in if my data read is a 5 and im decrementing that the 5 stays and the y values on the plot dont lower. any suggestions?

Comment: @AmatuerCoder101 Assuming we're talking about the inside of the line `plot(data(max(1,t-100):t),'-*r'); %%%Plot the most recent 100 values` this sounds like a typo? Did you maybe put `plot(data(max(1,data):t),'-*r');` or something similar? Can you either edit the initial question to include your updated code or send me a PM?

Answer (score 0):

plot(data(max(1,t-100):t),'-*r'); %%%Plot the most recent 100 values

This will plot 100 values then scroll across so the data moves to the left one spot per new data added to the graph which is exactly as wanted cheers